# how to make every 2nd pixel gray in image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image in matlab. I'm trying to make every 2nd peixel gray. Would anybody know how to do this?

[image: example image]

Comment: Like a checkerboard or only in a specific dimension?

Comment: @Suever in a checkerboard would be helpful, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to create the checkboard pattern is to create a rectangular grid ([`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)) and then find all elements where the column and row indices sum to an even number or not using [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html).

```
sz = size(rgbImage);
[row, col] = ndgrid(1:sz(1), 1:sz(2));
checkers = logical(mod(row + col, 2));
```

Another way to create this same logical `checkers` matrix is to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) which will drastically reduce the memory consumed by the previous operations.

```
checkers = bsxfun(@(x,y)mod(x + y, 2), 1:size(rgbImage, 1), (1:size(rgbImage, 2)).').';
```

[image]

Now we just need to use this logical matrix to index into `rgbImage` and set the relevant values to gray (128). An easy way to do this is to flatten the first dimensions of `rgbImage` so we can index into them directly with the logical matrix, `checkers`.

```
reshaped_image = reshape(rgbImage, [], 3);          % Flatten first two dims
reshaped_image(checkers, :) = 128;                  % Set all channels to 128
newImage = reshape(reshaped_image, size(rgbImage)); % Shape it back into original
```

[image]

**Update**

If you would like to apply this checkerboard pattern to *only* the white parts of your original `rgbImage`, you can definitely do that. For that you would need to create a logical matrix that indicates where the white pixels are. Then you want to find where the checkerboard pattern is AND (`&`) where the pixels are white.

```
isWhite = all(rgbImage == 255, 3);     % White pixels where all channels = 255
tochecker = checkers & isWhite;        % Combine with checkerboard
```

Then apply this pattern the same way.

```
reshaped_image = reshape(rgbImage, [], 3);          % Flatten first two dims
reshaped_image(tochecker, :) = 128;                 % Set all channels to 128
newImage = reshape(reshaped_image, size(rgbImage)); % Shape it back into original
```

If we apply this to the image in your post, we get the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Read image:

```
rgbImage = imread('photo.jpg');
```

2) Convert to a cell array, where each element represents a pixel though 1x1x3 uint8 rgb triplet:

```
cellArray = mat2cell(rgbImage, ones(size(rgbImage,1),1), ones(size(rgbImage,2),1), size(rgbImage,3));
```

3) Replace each second cell with gray color. Note we need to preserve original type and dimension, otherwise the following `cell2mat` call will fail:

```
cellArray(1:2:end) = {reshape(uint8([255,255,255]*0.1), [1,1,3])};
```

4) Convert back to matrix and display:

```
imageGray = cell2mat(cellArray);
imshow(imageGray);
```

**EDIT** *checkerboard*

If you want image to be colored as checkerboard, regardless of image dimensions, *step 3* could be replaced with:

```
linInd = 1:numel(cellArray);
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(cellArray), linInd);
toColor = mod(i+j,2) == 0;
cellArray(linInd(toColor)) = {reshape(uint8([255,255,255]*0.1), [1,1,3])};
```

Basically we only color those cells were i+j is even.

Comment: Just added a modification that gives you checkerboard. First piece of code colored each second pixel, so it depends on whether your height is even or odd. New code always produces checkboard appearance

Comment: Hi nirvana-mus, would it be possible to only color the pixel gray if the pixel is white? I have a black and white image and I'd like to only have the checkered areas in the white parts. I've posted an example picture in my original post.

Comment: @user6029533 I have updated my answer above this one to include the condition that the initial pixels should be white.