# Drawing a black rectangle in an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm facing a problem. I'm writing a script and wanted to apply this effect on a white image.

[image]

But now my image appears like this.

[image]

I'm stuck on this i write two for loops one for rows and second for columns which draw black lines according to image size `800x450` but how i draw black boxes.

Script:

```
        clear all;
        close all;
        clc;
        image = rgb2gray(imread('4.jpg'));
        b = cast(image,'double');
        out = 60*((b)./(max(max(b))));

        out = out + 195;

        [r,c,d] = size(out);

        x = floor(r/80);

        y = floor(c/160);

        %x rows
        for i = 1 : 88 : 450
            %  replaceable line
            out(i:i+x,:,:) = 0;

        end



        %y columns
        for i = 1 : 88 : 800
            %  replaceable line
            out(:,i:i+y,:) = 0;
        end

        final = cast(out,'uint8');

        imshow(final);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this part of code:

```
image = ones(450,800,3);%create white image
[row_len,column_len,rgb] = size(image);
side_vert = floor(row_len/5);
side_hor  = floor(column_len/9);
color = 1;
for(i = 1:side_vert:row_len)
    for(j = 1:side_hor:column_len - side_hor)
        if(color == 0)
            image(i:side_vert - 1 + i,j:j + side_hor - 1,:) = 0;
            color = 1;
        else
            color = 0;
        end;
    end;
end;
imshow(image);
```

Comment: can we change color from black to red

Comment: yeah, of course. just change the 9'th line to this:image(i:side_vert - 1 + i,j:j + side_hor - 1,2:3) = 0;

Comment: how`ones(450,800,3)` create the white image can you tell me in short words

Comment: RGB image is represented by 3 mXn matrices (or mXnX3 matrix). mXn is the location of each pixel and each matrix is "responsible" for each color:1 for red,2 for green and 3 for blue. Every element(pixel) in such matrix stores the intensity of each color. When we do ones(m,n,3) we get the matrix with intensity of red green and blue equals = 1, which is the maximum intensity and it represents the white color. When we set all of them to to be zero we get black color. And when we set only the elements of first matrix to be 1 we get a red color.

Comment: `m` represent number of columns and `n` for rows

Comment: In ones (m,n,3), m = rows, n = colums. But 800x450 means <colums>X<rows>

Comment: last question can i create blue image by using `ones` function

Comment: image = ones(450,800,3);
image(:,:,1:2) = 0;

Answer (score 0):

The trick for drawing a checkerboard, is to find cases where the x and y indices (when added together) are either odd or even.

```
sz = size(img);
[row, col] = ndgrid(1:sz(1), 1:sz(2));
checkers = logical(mod(row + col, 2));
```

Or more simply

```
checkers = bsxfun(@(x,y)mod(x + y, 2), 1:size(img, 1), (1:size(img, 2)).').';
```

This will return a matrix with 0 (black) and 1 (white) checkers.

[image]

If you want to change the size of the checkers you could do something like this.

```
sz = size(img);
checkersize = 10;
[row, col] = ndgrid(1:sz(1), 1:sz(2));
checkers = logical(mod(ceil(row / checkersize) + ceil(col/checkersize)),2);
```

Or simply

```
checkersize = 10;
checkers = bsxfun(@(x,y)mod(ceil(x/checkersize) + ceil(y/checkersize), 2), 1:size(img, 1), (1:size(img, 2)).').';
```

[image]

If you actually want to apply this effect to an image, you can use the `checkers` matrices above to index into your image and set values [similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000194/670206)

```
replacementColor = [0 0 0];                         % RGB
reshaped_image = reshape(img, [], 3);               % Flatten first two dims
C = repmat(replacementColor, [sum(checkers(:)), 1]);% Make color correct size
reshaped_image(checkers, :) = C;                    % Replace color
newImage = reshape(reshaped_image, size(img));      % Shape it back into original
```

Comment: what is `img` in `size(img)`

Comment: @HarveyClue I have used `img` in place of your variable `image` since `image` is the name of a built-in function and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [checkerboard](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/checkerboard.html) function:

```
k = 30;   %// size of each square in the checkerboard
img = checkerboard(k) < 0.5;
```

For some reason the function makes half of the checkerboard gray, so you have to use `< 0.5` (or `> 0.5`, depending on the ordering you want) to give you just the black and white image.

[image]